# How do I add "Terms and Conditions" (i.e. Required Actions) for users in Keycloak admin console via importing realm.json?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have imported realm.json (In admin console, Create Realm-> browse resource file) where existing users are also present.

```
"users" : [ {
"id" : "id",
"createdTimestamp" : 1622625059225,
"username" : "username",
"enabled" : true,
"totp" : false,
"emailVerified" : true,
"email" : "sample@test.com",
"credentials" : [ {
  "id" : "credential_id",
  "type" : "password",
  "createdDate" : 1622625153395,
  "secretData" : "{...}",
  "credentialData" : "...":{}}"
} ],
"disableableCredentialTypes" : [ ],
**"requiredActions" : [ "terms_and_conditions"],**
"realmRoles" : [ "user" ],
"clientRoles" : {
  "account" : [ "view", "manage" ]
},
"notBefore" : 0,
"groups" : [ "/groups" ]
```

}

I have enable "Terms and Conditions" from root **requiredActions**

```
"requiredActions" : [ {
"alias" : "terms_and_conditions",
"name" : "Terms and Conditions",
"providerId" : "terms_and_conditions",
"enabled" : true,
"defaultAction" : true,
"priority" : 10,
"config" : { }
```

}]

Now after importing the realm.json, I am able to see the "Terms and Conditions" in Users details tab.
[image]

**But "Terms and Conditions" page is not appearing while Login to application**.

Note: If I explicitly add terms and conditions from required actions dropdown then only it works fine.